# multibyte characters unicode in neovim status line

Tags: neovim, statusline, multibyte

I am trying to configure lualine plugin to display unicode of a multibyte character under the cursor. It is works fine for ASCII but not multibyte chars...

Can anyone share a working lua function? Thanks!